# Distribution of monochromatic edge counts in 2-colored square lattices

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

The question is how to compute in general the following: given integers $n$ and $k$, how many 2-colored $n \times n$ lattices have $k$ monochromatic edges. There are no diagonal edges.

---

**Observations**:

I noticed that when you do a plot of the distribution (normalized so that it's a probability distribution) for $n=10$, you get something which is approximately Gaussian in $k$.

[image]
I thought that it might have some relationship with the Central Limit Theorem, which is used to explain why Gaussians show up in so many places. The CLT says that the probability distribution of the average of a large number of IID random variables is Gaussian. The random variables in this case act as indicators of whether an edge is monochromatic or not. This then suggests a binomial approximation where the Bernoulli trials correspond to checking if an edge is monochromatic or not. I tried this out and it works well.

The insight from these approximations is that whether some edge is monochromatic or not is largely independent of other edges. Of course they actually *are* dependent so these approximations can't be perfect.

I imagine, and I haven't had a chance to test this, that the graphs of log probabilities of the actual probability distribution and its binomial approximation diverge as you go along the tails.

So can anyone give an exact formula?